# How can I pad a Swift array to make it bigger?

Tags: arrays, swift, numpy, padding

I'm porting some Python code to Swift and am having trouble resizing one of my arrays.

I have a Swift 2D array of size `3640`, but I want it to be of size `6960`.

I am at a loss as for how to do this. What I'm looking for is something like NumPy's pad function, but for Swift.

Here's how I've accomplished this in Python:

```
# Let mfccs be a 2D NumPy array of shape [40,91] and size 3640

max_pad_len = 174

pad_width = max_pad_len - mfccs.shape[1]

# Resize mfccs from size 3640 to size 6960

mfccs = np.pad(mfccs, pad_width=((0, 0), (0, pad_width)), mode='constant')

# Now mfccs has a shape [40, 174] and size 6960
```

How can I convert this code to Swift? I'm sure it's very straightforward, but it is beyond my skills at the moment. I'd be extremely grateful for any help, as I have puzzled over this for a very long time.

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: Thank you, @DávidPásztor. I'll show my work next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a 2D array and a max padding length:

```
let array2d = [[1, 2], [11, 12, 13], [21], [], [41, 42, 43, 44, 45]]
let maxPadLen = 4
```

you can pad it like this (note that it is done element-wise, since in Swift, a 2D array is an array of arrays and does not have a 2D shape like you could have in NumPy or Pandas):

```
let paddedArray2d = array2d.map {
    let padding = maxPadLen - $0.count
    if padding > 0 {
        return [Int](repeating: 0, count: padding) + $0
    } 
    return $0
} as [[Int]]
```

If you print out the initial `array2d` and the padded `paddedArray2d`, you would get:

```
Initial array:
[[1, 2], [11, 12, 13], [21], [], [41, 42, 43, 44, 45]]
Padded array:
[[0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 11, 12, 13], [0, 0, 0, 21], [0, 0, 0, 0], [41, 42, 43, 44, 45]]
```

Note how it is possible that there is an element with more items than maxPadLen, if you prefer to disallow it, you can do something when `padding < 0` in the map function, for example, cut overflowing items.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you @Daniel. I didn't know about the differences in arrays in Swift vs NumPy. A question: what does `padding` represent in your code example? It references itself in the second line of your second code block, but is not defined. Is it zero? An array of zeroes? Thank you again.

Comment: @Beowulf I fixed the code, now everything should be clear. `padding` just calculates how many 0s are needed